# Plane equation through point perpendicular to line.

Tags: analytic-geometry

I must write an equation for plane which goes through point $B(2; -3; 1)$ perpendicular to line $
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=2t-1 \\ 
y=7-3t \\ 
z=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$

From that I obtain line direction vector (normal vector of line?) $v=(2; -3; 0)$
And my plane equation is $$2(x-2)-3(y+3)+0=0$$ 
obtained using formula $A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)+C(z-z_0)=0$ (B values are with indexes)

I am pretty sure I have misunderstood something though.

Comment: it looks correct; the point is on the plane, and the normal vector of the plane has the same direction as the line; perhaps you should call the point $P$ instead of $B$, because you used $B$ for something else

Comment: What makes you think your answer is incorrect?

Comment: So what would the final answer be? Let us confirm for you through to the final step of your solution!

Comment: Well it's my first time doing analytic geometry problems so I assumed I most likely misunderstood something if I got it this easy... I guess it's correct, thanks for reviewing.

Comment: Your answer is correct except *(normal vector of line?)*. The vector is orthogonal to the plane, not the line.